# RJ45 jack to PCB

Tags: pcb, pins, rj45

Everyone, hello!

So I'm building a PCB in my head right now, and I just wanted to quickly eliminate a thought I had in my mind.

When I add a RJ45 jack connector to my PCB board, there are (depending on how the connector is build, of course (with LED or not, etc)) normally 8 PINs for the 8 wires in the cat5/6 cable.

I put together this quick picture:
[image]

Is this correct? Do the numbers on the RJ45 jack connector correspond with those on my cat wire?

Comment: Probably. But the best way to eliminate all doubts is to check the datasheet of this specific jack part.

Comment: Looks like a regular jack without magnetics, why just not check it with DMM?

Comment: The datasheet will tell you, some with magnetics might in rare cases have slightly different layouts

Comment: @dim it mentions on the documentation: "POSITION 1 INSERT TYPICAL" through "POSITION 8 INSERT TYPICAL", that doesn't really help me though, does it?

Comment: If the datasheet does not clearly state the pinout, you should either bin the part and buy a part with a half-decent datasheet, or meter it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this correct? Do the numbers on the RJ45 jack connector correspond with those on my cat wire?

Not necessarily. You have to use datasheet for the connector, and create *device* in your EDA tool as per datasheet with proper symbol and package.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you have labeled the plug contrary to convention; precisely backwards.

[image]

Your second problem is that pins out of the jack don't always correspond directly to the pins inside the jack, so you need to check the datasheet and or with a multimeter.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself asking this exact question at work this week after encountering an RJ45 connector with a somewhat different PCB-side pin-out than what I was expecting (I was expecting something along the lines of what the original poster suggests in their jack diagram).

Digging a little deeper, I found there are two common PCB-side pin-out configurations.  This datasheet from TE Connectivity labels them as "traditional" and "Category 5":
[5558341-1 Datasheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=5558341&DocType=Customer%20Drawing&DocLang=English)

Similarly, browsing through entries in the tables in this catalog document indicates a mix of pin-outs out there:
[TE Connectivity modular jacks catalog](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1-1773464-9_MODULAR_JACKS&DocType=Data%20Sheet&DocLang=English)

As other people have suggested, definitely check the datasheet for the specific part you intend to use.  I realize this answer comes long after the original question was posted, but hopefully it helps someone else avoid the moment of excitement I experienced during a PCB layout review yesterday afternoon.